What does バカ抜かす mean?
彼がバカ抜かす前に俺がこの事件を終わらす
The character says this toward his rival who stole something from him and plans to end matter in his own way.
What does exactly バカ抜かす mean? Make a mess? Say something stupid?

「バカを抜かす」 usually means 「バカなことを言う」(say something stupid/silly).
抜かす can mean "to say, to speak." eg 「何抜かしてやがる」(What are you saying?)「ふざけたことをぬかすな」「たわけたことぬかせ！」(Don't be silly.)
